# AWS Lambda S3 event infinite loop

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to use S3 events to publish to AWS Lambda whenever a video file (.mp4) gets uploaded, so that it can be compressed. The problem is that the path to the video file is stored in RDS, so I want the path to remain the same after compression. From what I've read, replacing the file will again call the `Object Created` event leading to an infinite loop.

Is there any way to replace the file without triggering any event? What are my options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an ungraceful solution to this problem, which is not documented anywhere.

The `event` parameter in the Lambda function contains a `userIdentity` dict which contains `principalId`. For an event which originated because of AWS Lambda (like updating S3 object as mentioned in question), this `principalId` contains the name of the lambda function appended at the end.

Therefore, by checking the `principalId` one can deduce whether the event came from Lambda or not, and accordingly compress or not.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that you cannot completely distinguish. From the [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-event-notification/) the following events are supported:

- `s3:ObjectCreated:Put` – An object was created by an HTTP PUT operation.
- `s3:ObjectCreated:Post` – An object was created by HTTP POST operation.
- `s3:ObjectCreated:Copy` – An object was created an S3 copy operation.
- `s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload` – An object was created by the completion of a S3 multi-part upload.
- `s3:ObjectCreated:*` – An object was created by one of the event types listed above or by a similar object creation event added in the future.
- `s3:ReducedRedundancyObjectLost` – An S3 object stored with Reduced Redundancy has been lost.

The architecture that I would generally see for this type of problem is having 2 S3 buckets

- 1 S3 Bucket stores the source material without any modification, this would trigger the Lambda event.
- 1 S3 Bucket stores the processed artifact, from the compressed output.

By doing this you can store the original, and rerun if needed to autocorrect.

Comment: Can I use the `ObjectCreated:Put` request for AWS Lambda, and `Post` for normal uploading to S3 and to trigger S3 events?

Comment: Yes you can filter to use ObjectCreated:Post for uploads. By default post is via the browser, whereas put is via CLI I believe.